# Can't access elements of a php array

Tags: php, arrays, forms

I am really tearing my hair out and I wondered if anyone can see what I am doing wrong. I have a form which fills an array "Rehearsals". So far so good. If after I press submit, I recover the values of rehearsal, I can get a print_r of the variable, but the variable itself has no contents so:

```
$rhearsal = $_POST['rehearsal'];
foreach($rhearsal as $row) {
    print_r($row);
    echo "<br>plan:" . $row->plan . "<br><br>";
}
```

Gives the output:

```
Array ( 
    [Name] => A***** M***** 
    [Rehearsal_no] => 1 
    [Rehearsal] => Spring15-150106-1900 
    [plan] => Yes 
    [actual] => Yes 
) 
plan:
```

In other words, the variable exists in `$row` when I print it using print_r, but when I try to access it with `$row->plan` it has a null value.

I have done this lots of times before with variables, but not with input forms. If it is any help, the input form is of the form: `<input type='hidden' name='rehearsal[$counter][Name]' value='$usern'>`where `$counter` is an incrementing counter.

Anyone got any ideas - I have wasted a day trying to figure this out - typing and retyping in different ways. Thanks :)

Comment: `$row['plan']` since `$row` is an `array`, not an object

Comment: You must not be using: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
$rhearsal = $_POST['rehearsal'];
foreach($rhearsal as $row) {
    print_r($row);
    echo "<br>plan:" . $row['plan'] . "<br><br>";
}
```

More importantly, this bit:

```
$row['plan'];
```

As `$row` is an array, you grab it this way.

Objects are grabbed by using `->`.

Comment: Brilliant - thanks. Just goes to show it pays to ask.  I am still not sure what the difference between an array and an object is, but I will do some further research. :)

Comment: @Mishutka if this answer has helped you can you please press the tick to the left of the answer box to mark it as answered!

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to access the values in `$row` using the object notation then you can just convert `$row` to an object:

```
$rhearsal = $_POST['rehearsal'];
foreach($rhearsal as $row) {
    print_r($row);           // here $row is an array()
    $row = (object)$row;
    print_r($row);           // and now it's an object (stdClass)
    echo "<br>plan:" . $row->plan . "<br><br>";        // this works as expected
}
```